# XAML DataGrid filtering won't apply the filter

Tags: xaml, datagrid, observablecollection

I'm trying to create a form that has two tabs, each with a DataGrid with a different filter on it.  I've created the filters as such:

```
ObservableCollection<ParcelVoucherDetails> _voucherDetails = new ObservableCollection<ParcelVoucherDetails>();

CollectionView cvFreightOut = new CollectionView(_voucherDetails);
cvFreightOut.Filter += FreightOutFilter;
dgFreightOut.ItemsSource = cvFreightOut;

CollectionView cvFreightIn = new CollectionView(_voucherDetails);
cvFreightIn.Filter += FreightInFilter;
dgFreightIn.ItemsSource = cvFreightIn;
```

I then created the filters as such:

```
        public bool FreightOutFilter(object o)
    {
        ParcelVoucherDetails p = o as ParcelVoucherDetails;
        if (p != null)
        {
            return (p.Type == "Freight Out");
        }
        return false;
    }

    public bool FreightInFilter(object o)
    {
        ParcelVoucherDetails p = o as ParcelVoucherDetails;
        if (p != null)
        {
            return (p.Type == "Freight In");
        }
        return false;
    }
```

Now, here's where it gets annoying.  During a later event, when I add items to the ObservableCollection, I can see the filters firing and accepting or denying the filter as expected, but ALL the items still appear on both DataGrids.

I've tried using CollectionViewSource, and that also doesn't work.  The only way I can get any filtering to work at all is to skip the ObservableCollection and use a DataTable with DataViews.  I'd like to avoid that here, because of the convenience in the rest of the code for using the ObservableCollection.

Has anyone seen this actually work, and if so, how?

Answer (score 2):

I finally found it after banging my head on the wall.  I feel ridiculous right now, but I had to share the solution:

```
ListCollectionView cvFO = new ListCollectionView(_voucherDetails);
cvFO.Filter += FreightOutFilter;
dgFreightOut.ItemsSource = cvFO;

ListCollectionView cvFI = new ListCollectionView(_voucherDetails);
cvFI.Filter += FreightInFilter;
dgFreightIn.ItemsSource = cvFI;
```

This sets the filters separately.  Apparently, using a generic CollectionView instead of a ListCollectionView is a no-no.  :)